# Customize Login Page in New Universal Login?

Tags: configuration, auth0

We want to improve the branding of our existing login page. After going through the docs, I have couple of questions:

1. As per the docs, we can use page templates & customize the html in new universal login. The page template has to have `{%- auth0:widget -%}`. Now, If I want to improve the branding of the widget itself, can i use the no-code editor to do so? Will the combination of page templates and no-code editor work?
2. As per docs, I understand that page templates can be updated only via management apis. But when I navigate to "Branding > Universal Login > Advanced Options > Login", I can enable "Customize Login Page" and provide custom HTML there. Can I provide my page templates here? Or is this only meant for Classic Universal Login where complete HTML (using `auth0.js` & other cdns) can be changed? (If "Customize Login Page" is only for Classic Universal Login, why is it also shown when I have enabled New Universal Login?)